# How to use 'this' keyword when calling a base constructor

Tags: c#

```
abstract class Foo 
{
    private readonly FooAttributeCollection attributes;

    public Foo(FooAttributeCollection attributes) 
    {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}

class FooAttributeCollection 
{
    public FooAttributeCollection(Foo owner) 
    {
    }
}

class Bar : Foo 
{
    public Bar() : base(new FooAttributeCollection(this)) 
    {
    }
}
```

Supposing that I have to write a code like above. and the classes `Foo` and `FooAttributeCollection` cannot be modified.

When I write `Bar` class like that, an error mentioned below:

> 'this' keyword cannot be used in this context.

occurs near the line `base(...)`

Is there any good idea to handle with this matter?

Comment: You can't reference the object (using `this` or otherwise) until *after* the object has been constructed.  I'm not sure that this is possible.

Comment: First passing `null`, next settings `attributes` via reflection.

Comment: Would it be possible for the `Foo` constructor to call `new FooAttributeCollection(this)` within its body instead? That would solve the problem. Unfortunately we don't know the constraints here.

Comment: Base constructors are executed before the derived one so when `base` is called, it's not sure that `this` was constructed at all (I think that's the correct wording but I'm not sure). I think instead of throwing an error your way, the developers of c# could also have decided to make `this` be `null` but it would always be `null` in that context therefore they just straight up banned it (that's a bit of an assumption thought, maybe there are also technical reasons I don't know about).

Comment: Interesting puzzle but this is a design error in Foo and FooAttributeCollection. There is no way a Foo can be the owner of its own Attributes this way.

Comment: The controls in `System.Web.UI.WebControls/HtmlControls` have a way around this, but applying that technique would require modifying `Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **Foo** and **FooAttributeCollection** can't be modified, this code seems to be a bad design.
To instantiate a derivated Foo class you must instantiate FooAttributeCollection before and to instantiate FooAttributeCollection  you must instantiate the same derivated Foo class.
Its a endless circular dependency impossible to resolve without 'cheating'

perhaps this problem can be resolve by refection (as say by Uwe Keim), or by using real proxy/dynamic proxy to create a proxy of DerivedClass.

Comment: I intended to write something like inner class in Java. If so, I have to find other ways.

Comment: For your information Inner class(aka nested type) definition is possible in C# [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)

Answer (score 1):

You can't write:

```
public Bar() : base(new FooAttributeCollection(this))
```

Because `this`, the current object, must be put in the implementation of a method, not in the method signature: here you have no access to the current instance of the object.

You can't do a such thing in every method declaration because you are out of the implementation scope, you are in the type def scope i.e. in the "interface" of the class, in its definition.

The use of calling base or side constructor with `base` or `this` keyword is a particular language construction to pass parameters that are not the instance of the class itself.

You can use the @Tohm solution to solve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't affect attributes in abstract class ? If you want in FooAttributeCollection you can cast owner in Bar class.

```cs
abstract class Foo 
{
    private readonly FooAttributeCollection attributes;

    public Foo(FooAttributeCollection attributes=null) 
    {
        if(attributes = null) {attributes = new FooAttributeCollection(this);}
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}

class FooAttributeCollection 
{
    public FooAttributeCollection(Foo owner) 
    {
        var ownerInBar = owner as Bar;

    }
}

class Bar : Foo 
{
    public Bar() : base() 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: "and the classes Foo and FooAttributeCollection cannot be modified"

Comment: It is still the only sensible way out.

Answer (score 0):

the class needs to be constructed before you can access the `this` keyword.

You can try the bellow.

```
class Bar : Foo
    {
        private readonly FooAttributeCollection attributes;
        public Bar() : base(null)
        {
            var attributes = new FooAttributeCollection(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP said the `Foo` class cannot be modified.

Comment: How will you add your `fooAttr` to `attributes` in `Foo`?

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the problem, the *reason* why you can't use `this` in that context is correct (if you take "access" to mean "let the outside world access it").

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

```
public class Bar : Foo
    {
        public Bar(FooAttributeCollection attributes) : base(attributes)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Other Example:**

```
public class BaseClass
    {
        int num;
        public BaseClass(int i)
        {
            num = i;
            Console.WriteLine("in BaseClass(int i)");
        }
    }
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {         
        // This constructor will call BaseClass.BaseClass(int i)
        public DerivedClass(int i) : base(i)
        {
        }
    }
```